# using windows service can we copy files from one computer to another computer C#.net?

Tags: c#

I have one service that will create a text  file to local machine and then need to copy the same file to  another server .

I am using   " File.Copy(SourceFilePath, TargetFilePath, true);"
and getting an exception at the target file path "access denied. I am able to copy the  files manually to that location ( TargetFilePath) .

any idea , what is going wrong ??

I don't have any network drive mapping with this target location.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic permissions issue.  You need to make sure that the service is running in the context of a user with the ability to copy files.  Since you need to copy files around, I would suggest using a user that is in the Backup Operators group, although you might want something more restrictive for your scenario.

Edit:  Since you're also copying to another server, your user will need to have rights on that server as well.  For that purpose, you might run your service under a domain account (assuming your machines are both in a domain).  You can also test by using the Run As... option on a console app with the same code - that way you can debug permissions issues before setting up the service.

Answer (score 0):

The account that the service is running on must have access to the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

From the source machine can you manually copy the files to the Target?

C:>Xcopy \sourcemachine\dir*.txt \TargetMachine\dir\ /Y/K/D/C

That should help you narrow it down if the problem is related to code or permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running on a domain, your code can impersonate a user on the other machine that does have rights.